# Python pandas datetime difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have this:

```
x[l[0]] =  pd.to_datetime(x[l[0]], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Where `l=list(x)`

How can I have the difference between this objects in seconds, If I do this

```
x[l[0]][1]-x[l[0]][2]
```

It returns me a timedelta object

```
print (x[:5])
              LogDate  Query_BoxID_ID  Query_Function_ID  SC_Win32_Status
0 2017-06-15 09:50:14              12                 24                0
1 2017-06-15 09:50:14              12                 26                0
2 2017-06-15 09:50:14              12                 26                0
3 2017-06-15 09:50:14              12                 30                0
4 2017-06-15 09:50:32              12                 19                0
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data, `print (x[:5])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just do

```
(x[l[0]][1]-x[l[0]][2]).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) for timedeltas, which are converted by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
#convert column to datetime
x['LogDate'] = pd.to_datetime(x['LogDate'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#first value is NaN always, so replaced to 0 by fillna and cast to int
a = x['LogDate'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (a)
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4    18
Name: LogDate, dtype: int32
```

---

```
b = int((x.loc[0, 'LogDate'] - x.loc[0, 'LogDate']).total_seconds())
print (b)
0
```

Comment: But how can I have the difference between the 1st two rows? Without having all the differences

Comment: Yes, total_seconds is solution. But in pandas obvoisly working with all columns, so first was added solution for all differences.